# Java run problems from terminal

Tags: java, java-native-interface, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I'm using a cloud VM in which Ubuntu is installed. Java version installed is:

> java version "1.8.0_66" 
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)  
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

I've never used terminal to compile and run programs. However, this program works using Eclipse.

I have to use two jars when I compile my java program: `disco-2.1.jar` and `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar`. The terminal command I use is:

```
javac -cp '/home/ubuntu/workspace/sem/*' USem.java
```

Using `/home/ubuntu/workspace/sem/*` adds disco and sqlite jars to the classpath.

This creates my `USem.class` file in `sem` directory, without errors. Those jars are contained in `sem` directory.

`USem.java` contains this part of code, starting from the beginning:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException;

import de.linguatools.disco.CorruptConfigFileException;
import de.linguatools.disco.DISCO;
import de.linguatools.disco.TextSimilarity;
import de.linguatools.disco.DISCO.SimilarityMeasure;

public class USem {

//irrelevant code here

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CorruptConfigFileException, SQLException{
```

The problem starts when I run this in the terminal:

```
java USem
```

The terminal shows me:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   de/linguatools/disco/CorruptConfigFileException
>            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>            at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
>            at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
>            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
>            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   de.linguatools.disco.CorruptConfigFileException
>            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>            ... 7 more

I think there's a problem with `disco-2.1.jar`. I checked the jar classes contained in it and everything was ok.

My workspace is organized like so:

`home/ubuntu/workspace/sem`

In the `sem` directory I have my `.java` file and the `.jar` files are added there.

What am I doing wrong? I tried uninstalling JDK and reinstalling it, changing the terminal folder in which I run commands, but nothing changed.

--Update--

Now I wrote

```
java -cp '/home/ubuntu/workspace/sem/*' USem
```

However, I obtained

> Error: Could not find or load main class USem

Comment: You need the same `-cp  '/home/ubuntu/workspace/sem/*'` when you run it as well, not just when you compile it.

Comment: specify the classpath at runtime as well. Failing that, CorruptConfigFileException might be rarely thrown and not present in you classpath.

Comment: Ok, now I did it and now the problem is Error: Could not find or load main class USem

Answer (score 1):

Add Disco jar (or any other required jar for that matter) to classpath while executing java command

`java -cp "Whatever.jar" my.package.MainClass`

Answer (score 0):

The default classpath when there's no `-classpath` argument and no `CLASSPATH` environment variable is `.`. Now when your class file is in your working directory and you call `java USem`, Java finds your class but not the classes in the other jar files because these are not in the classpath.

When you add `-cp '/home/ubuntu/workspace/sem/*'` Java will find the classes in the jar files. But this also overrides the default classpath, so `.` is no more in there, therefore Java doesn't find your own class anymore. You need to explicitly add `.` (or `/home/ubuntu/workspace/sem`) again: `-cp '.:/home/ubuntu/workspace/sem/*'`

Answer (score 0):

All your comments were useful. I'd like to post my solution.
I declared CLASSPATH environment

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/ubuntu/workspace/sem/disco-2.1.jar:**other paths for other external jars**:.
```

I moved into workspace and compiled .class file

```
javac -cp 'sem/*' sem/USem.java
```

Then I moved into sem and run

```
java USem
```

and worked.

Answer (score 0):

move all the required jars in the`jre/lib/ext` folder and simply run the command
java filename 
worked for me!